# how to write a regex to parse refs/changes

Tags: python

I have the following as input. I am trying to write a regular expression which yields the below output. Can anyone provide
input on how to do this?

```
INPUT:-

refs/changes/44/1025744/3
refs/changes/62/1025962/5 
refs/changes/45/913745/2

OUTPUT:-
1025744/3
1025962/5 
913745/2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the actual import format, a regex is not needed:

```
>>> source = """\
... refs/changes/44/1025744/3
... refs/changes/62/1025962/5
... refs/changes/45/913745/2
... """
>>> output = [line.split('/', 3)[-1] for line in source.splitlines()]
>>> output[0]
'1025744/3'
>>> output[1]
'1025962/5'
```

You can also have them all in one string, like this:

```
>>> ' '.join(line.split('/', 3)[-1] for line in source.splitlines())
'1025744/3 1025962/5 913745/2'
```

Comment: can I get the output as 1025744/3 1025962/5 913745/2

Comment: You mean `' '.join(output)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> input="""refs/changes/44/1025744/3
... refs/changes/62/1025962/5 
... refs/changes/45/913745/2"""
>>> res=re.findall(r'.*/.*/.*/(.*/.*)',input)
>>> for i in res:
...    print i
... 
1025744/3
1025962/5 
913745/2
```

Comment: am getting the output as ['1025744/3', '1025962/5 ', '913745/2'] ,can I get the output as 1025744/3 1025962/5 913745/2

Comment: Print each value using a loop

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeding the input line by line, you could do this:

```
import re
instr = 'refs/changes/44/1025744/3'
print get_match(instr)

def get_match():
    match = re.match("^(refs/changes/[0-9]*/)([0-9/]*)", instr)
    if match:
        return match.group(2)
```